# Configure binding of 2 controllers to a single html file using Javascript state

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, email

I'm new to web development, and I'm trying to figure how to bind two controllers to an html file.

The reason, is that I want to send an email from the app using PHP code, and the current controller is written in Javascript, so a figured a possible solution can be to add a PHP controller.

I'm working on someone else's code and the way he configured the JS controller with the html file is:

```
angular.module('sbAdminApp', [
    'oc.lazyLoad',
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'angular-loading-bar',
    'multipleSelect'
  ])
  .config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider','$ocLazyLoadProvider',function ($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider,$ocLazyLoadProvider) {

$ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
  debug:false,
  events:true,
});

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/enter');

$stateProvider
  .state('dashboard', {
    url:'/dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/main.html',
    resolve: {
        loadMyDirectives:function($ocLazyLoad){
            return $ocLazyLoad.load(
            {
                name:'sbAdminApp',
                files:[
                'scripts/directives/header/header.js',
                'scripts/directives/header/header-notification/header-notification.js',
                'scripts/directives/sidebar/sidebar.js',
                'scripts/directives/sidebar/sidebar-search/sidebar-search.js'
                ]
            }),
            $ocLazyLoad.load(
            {
               ...
               ...
.state('enter',{
  templateUrl:'views/pages/enter.html',
  url:'/enter',
  controller:'enterController',
  resolve: {
    loadMyFile:function($ocLazyLoad) {
      return $ocLazyLoad.load({
          name:'sbAdminApp',
          files:['scripts/controllers/enterController.js','styles/enter.css']
      })
    }
  }
})
```

My goal is to associate `enter.html` with a PHP controller.

How should I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Your current project is Angular 1.X version. In order to have PHP running on your page you need to have the .html template as .php. But why would you mix php and angular anyway? Instead create a new PHP file which handles the email sending and from the javascript file trigger that function in some location. This way you don't mix these two things. For example sendEmail.php as file

Comment: How can I trigger PHP function out of Javascript file?

Comment: Use the angular HTTP service: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post

You have to edit the controller, "enterController" in your code, inject HTTP there. Like this: 

    .controller('enterController', ['$http', ....

Then inside the controller function trigger php call

$http.post('/sendEmail.php', data, config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);

Comment: I see. Ok, I'll go with it see how it works